# How do I sort the elements in my list of dictionaries using a defined function with two parameters

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a code in which I need to sort the elements of my dictionary in my main list using a function I define with two parameters. The first parameter is my list with dictionaries and the second one has to be a boolean set to True by default. I want my output to be the sorted list of **sorted** countries the authors are from if I only write "get_diff_countries(list_authors)" and the output of not sorted countries if I call "get_diff_countries(list_authors, False)". Here is my code so far:

```
###  Part 1 

list_authors = [{'author_id' : 1, 'fullname': 'Jenine Thomson', 'age' : 58, 'country' : 'Ecuador', 'continent' : 'South America'},
                {'author_id' : 2, 'fullname': 'Lavonna Mayberry', 'age' : 92, 'country' : 'France', 'continent' : 'Europe'},
                {'author_id' : 3, 'fullname': 'Lewis Strain', 'age' : 29, 'country' : 'Korea (Republic of)', 'continent' : 'asia'}, ...]

list_books = [{'id': 1, 'title': 'The Fractured Birds', 'genre': 'Crime', 'nberPages': 500, 'price': 316.00, 'author_id': 20},
              {'id': 2, 'title': 'Solar Eclipse of the Heart', 'genre': 'Romance', 'nberPages': 444, 'price': 204.00, 'author_id': 5},
              {'id': 3, 'title': 'The dark maid', 'genre': 'Mystery', 'nberPages': 277, 'price': 65.00, 'author_id': 8}, ...]

###  Part 2

def get_diff_countries(alist, sorted=True):
    
    list1 = []
    
    for dict in alist:
        list1.append(dict['country'])
    return list1
print(get_diff_countries(list_authors))
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example of the sort of output you're looking for, even if it's just a couple of lines.

Comment: So what's the need for `list_books` in this code? You just want to sort `country` in `list_books` and return it as a `list`, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can firstly convert this into a `pandas` dataframe and then sort the dataframe by the `country` column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list_authors)
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by = "country")
```

To get the dataframe in a dictionary do this,

```
df_values = sorted_df.values
list(map(lambda row: dict(zip(df.columns, row)), df_values))
```

This would return the sorted dictionary you desire.

---

To write this all in a function do this,

```
def get_diff_countries(alist, sorted = True):
  df = pd.DataFrame(alist)
  df_values = df.sort_values(by = "country", ascending = sorted).values

  return list(map(lambda row: dict(zip(df.columns, row)), df_values))
```

Comment: Not every nail needs the pandas hammer…

Comment: @deceze I just love using it in everything. Like if you check out my past few answers too...all have pandas in places where it wasn't actually needed

Comment: Good for you, but foisting pandas as a dependency on people to solve a problem that can be solved just fine with builtins is… something of a big ask.

Comment: @deceze That's true. I'll try solving my future questions without using any external libraries from now on. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Does this what you want to do:

```
def get_diff_countries(alist, sort=True):
    countries = (record["country"] for record in alist)
    return sorted(countries) if sort else list(countries)
```

I wouldn't use `sorted` as variable name because this overwrites access to the built-in function [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#sorted), which is useful here. The `(...)` is a generater expression that is evaluated lazily, i.e. only once used as argument for `sorted()` or `list()`.